# How can you identify and forward "not logged in" users back to login page?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, deployment-descriptor

I have created a web application using JSP, Servlet and JDBC (NO FRAMEWORKS). We have form based authentication security, where the user has to log in first. The user names and passwords are in the database and as in any internet based web application, user name and passwords are created by users them selves.

We have used `Java Sessions` to identify the users and find out whether the person is logged in or not. what we do is in every servlet page and JSP page we check whether the session is new or not and whether the session is available, if there is any issue we forward the users back to the login page. This protects the users directly accessing URL's like `www.xxx.com/questions?idEmployee=1`.

Now the issue comes. I know we don't have to write the java code in every page to check whether the person is logged in or not. There is something we can do with the deployment descriptor right? So it can automatically check the things and forward the users.

However the answers I found in google are all about hard coding the user name and password to the deployment descriptor, so it is useless for us. So, how can we solve this problem without hard coding the usernames and passwords to the deployment descriptor?

Comment: These stuffs you always do in Filters.

Comment: @RohitJain: Didn't get that.

Comment: Also, don't use the fact that a session exists to know if the user is logged in. Store a flag, or the basic logged-in user information, in the session, and use the presence of this flag/user information to decide. You can perfectly use a session even for not logged-in users. And that's the default with JSPs, BTW.

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html

Comment: @JBNizet: You mean save the information which can identify the user info right? Yeah we do save user name and passwrd in session,.

Comment: @JB Nizet: filters will  protect the servlets but what about jsp?

Comment: Filters can be mapped to url patterns. So if you map a servlet to /protected/*, then any servlet or JSPunder /propected/ will be filtered.

Comment: @JB Nizet: /* means all right? So maybe not the best choice because login page can also be mapped, isn't it..

Comment: Nothing prevents you to do something different in the filter if the path is the path of the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is write one Filter class(Servlet) that will avoid rewrite the code each and every JSP files.

In filter class you can validate the session.

Comment: filters will protect the servlets but what about jsp?

Answer (score 0):

- Option 1: As suggested by others use `Filters`.
- Option 2: Write a jsp to validate session and redirect user if required. Now import the said jsp in reset of the jsp's which require valid session.

Comment: filters will protect the servlets but what about jsp?